# Sonarqube plugin matrix says LTS 6.7.2 has SonarJava 5.1.1 but it does not appear to

Tags: java, sonarqube, jacoco, sonarqube-scan

Sonarqube plugin matrix says that LTS 6.7.2 should have SonarJava 5.1.1

However, we can see that it only has 4.15.

This is important because we need the proper version of jacoco (0.8.0) rather than 0.7.9.

When will this actually be updated in LTS? Please update your documentation to correctly reflect the version.

Answer (score 4):

The [Plugin Version Matrix](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Plugin+Version+Matrix) shows *compatibility*, not what was shipped together. So you can read it as saying SonarJava 5.1.1 is *compatible* with SonarQube 6.7.2. Not that the LTS is *shipped* with that version of the analyzer.

Regarding point versions of SonarQube, they do not appear explicitly in the matrix, but you can safely assume that anything that's compatible with `x.y` (which is what's shown in the matrix) is also compatible with `x.y.1`, `x.y.2`, `x.y.3`, `...`. That kind of two-dot version number indicates a bug fix, so there won't be any (plugin compatibility-breaking) API changes in them.

Comment: OK Thank you. Is that also true for 6.7.1?

Comment: Yes, @TheComputerGuy.Jeff. There are (self-imposed) limitations to how that matrix is generated. We don't include every point version in it on the assumption that bug fix releases will... only fix bugs, not changes APIs/break compatibility.